# Is there an HTML <input type="number"> string equivalent to cycle through text elements?

Tags: html, user-interface, text

Is there a text/string equivalent for `<input type="number">` which cycles through text/string elements instead of numbers? I've had a look at w3schools but to no avail.

I'd like for the user to select one of four string options in a similar manner as the number spinner (so instead of cycling through numbers they cycle through the four options)

Comment: Could you please explain actually what you want

Comment: I'd like for the user to cycle though four string elements (imoto, ithanga, ivubma and idlela) in the same way the HTML <input type="number"> cycles through numbers.

Comment: you can use select list

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp